# (older) Apple wireless keyboard connected & working - but not "recognised" by keyboard assistant (Big Sur)

Tags: keyboard, bluetooth, big-sur, apple-silicon, firmware

Okay, this might be a weird one.
I have an older Apple wireless keyboard (with new AA batteries) connected to my M1 MacBook Air running lates macOS Big Sur.
It works. It shows in the bluetooth menu as my keyboard; every button works.

BUT: the thing **eats batteries like crazy** (14days max on new batteries).
So I searched and found, that there is a firmware update - which I now want to install.
But the keyboard is never "recognised" in the sense that:

1. The installer (`AlKybdFirmwareUpdate.dmg`) complains that *no Apple keyboard (Aluminum)* was found.
2. the keyboard settings pane offers to "change keyboard type..." after which it wants to identify the keyboard ("press button to the right of your left shift key"). When I hit that button it complains, that the keyboard cannot be identified (but the button works!).

What's going on here?
Does this firmware update maybe not work on newer Macs, because this issue came up back in Snow Leopard? Is this keyboard just EOL?

PS: I'm running Big Sur in German, so maybe some of my "translations" are a bit off...

Comment: Never tried it, but I wonder if it would work if you connected over USB, at least to get the update onto it. I don't have anything I can test, all my older aluminium keyboards are wired & the one for the M1 is brand new.

Comment: But this keyboard does not *have* any USB port. Wait, does that mean that I don't have what they call the "Aluminum keyboard"? (for clarity: I have one of these here: https://images.app.goo.gl/hsfSNZE7PPo8yDN26)

Comment: ah… OK. I didn't realise it was one of those - it's not an 'aluminium kbd' it's 'wireless' .Never owned one myself. The newer ones are USB chargeable & seem to last maybe 4 - 6 weeks between charges, even when used most of the day. Have a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apple_Wireless_Keyboard & see if you can tell precisely which model it is, then https://support.apple.com/en_US/downloads/keyboards has a few versions of firmware updates, maybe one of those is better suited. I'd also look into rechargeable batteries, make a lot of sense over time.